# おはよう pitch accent in 関西弁

Tags: dialects, pitch-accent

I think in 標準語 it goes おはよう{LHHH}. I just heard someone from 大阪 say おはよう, but I wasn't sure it was おはよう{LHLL} or something else, but it sounded very different from 標準語. How is it pronounced in 関西弁?

Comment: FYI https://kaigaino.net/archives/8626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it as [おはよう]【LLHL】.